# Android FireStore retrieve as list

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> Collection

[image]

> I have succeed in pushing data as following way:

```
 private void onAddItemsClicked() {
    // Get a reference to the restaurants collection
    CollectionReference quotes = mFirestore.collection("quotes");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Get a random Restaurant POJO
        TaskItem item = new TaskItem();
        item.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        item.setTitle("good life is key to success " + i);
        item.setCategory("Life " + i);

        // Add a new document to the restaurants collection
        quotes.add(item);
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve it in my custom list object let's say `List<TaskItem> mList;` which contains all Firestore data.

I tried following way and it shows no such document.

```
        mQuery = mFirestore.collection("quotes");
        mQuery.document().get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

What am I missing here? Any reference or help

Comment: Please read docs, because `mQuery.document().get().` looks like retriving single document. This is very strange

Comment: Yes it should retrieve single document but still I am getting "No such Document"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
mQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<TaskItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                TaskItem taskItem = document.toObject(TaskItem.class);
                list.add(taskItem);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

The `list` contains now, all your `TaskItem` objects.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing Map<String, Object> and iterate over objects but this seems right solution.